# Play local audio files in ios cordova

Tags: ios, cordova, audio, media

I am using media plugin to play local audio files (inside /www folder). This perfectly works in android but in iOS the error "Cannot play the audio file from resource…." is coming.
Please check the below screenshot and coding. How should i solve this to play local audio files.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    function getPhoneGapPath() {

        'use strict';
        var path = window.location.pathname;
        var phoneGapPath = path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        return phoneGapPath;
    };


    // Audio player
    var my_media = null;
    var mediaTimer = null;

    // Play audio
    function playAudio() {
        if (my_media == null) {
            // Create Media object from src
            my_media = new Media(getPhoneGapPath() +'button-click.wav', onSuccess, onError);
        } // else play current audio
        // Play audio
        my_media.play();
    }

    // Pause audio
    //
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.pause();
        }
    }

    // Stop audio
    function stopAudio() {
        if (my_media) {
            my_media.stop();
        }
        clearInterval(mediaTimer);
        mediaTimer = null;
    }

    // onSuccess Callback
    function onSuccess() {
        console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
    }

    // onError Callback
    function onError(error) {
        alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }

    </script>
```